# Learning Apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am working on a project which requires manipulation of MS word document using Java. I have found that `Apache POI` is the best API to do that.
But I could not properly understand the use of POI from [this link](http://poi.apache.org/hwpf/index.html) . Also, I was not able to SVN check-out the source from [here](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/trunk/src/scratchpad/src/org/apache/poi/).
Can anyone please help me with using POI or some sample code.
Thanks.

EDIT: Can I edit an existing Word template document and replace the place holders with the text I want using POI?

Comment: See also this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3562214/230513).

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2253779/learning-apache-poi-for-java

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1) You can [download](http://poi.apache.org/download.html) POI as a .zip or .tar.gz file (WinZip should understand both formats) [here](http://poi.apache.org/download.html).

2) The Quick Guide is [here](http://poi.apache.org/hwpf/quick-guide.html).

3) [This Quick Guide](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/trunk/src/scratchpad/testcases/org/apache/poi/hwpf/) points to the unit tests, which make for excellent sample code.

4) Here's another good [howto](http://www.javatips.net/blog/2011/12/read-and-write-excel-with-java-poi) (it's for Excel, but applicable to Word).

Answer (score 8):

You need busy [developer's guide](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html) .

Answer (score 2):

Apache POI actually contains many APIs, each API provide ability to operate particular file. Manual of each API can be found at [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/), you can see a list of API at left which link to the individual pages. You can find quick guide in it.

Last, you can just download source distribution at download page.

Answer (score 1):

Try this site: http://www.roseindia.net/java/poi/

It contains code samples.

Comment: roseIndia does not maintain standard examples