# Issue while reading Excel document (Java code)

Tags: java, exception, apache-poi

I have some Java code which reads the Excel data. On running the Java code, it's showing the following error. Help me resolve the same. Also, I need to know other method of reading *.xlsx* file.

(A small edit) how I can print rows with their respective columns. For example:

```
Age
19
20
21

Salary
35k
20k
40k
.
.
.
```

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.OfficeXmlFileException: The supplied
>   data appears to be in the Office 2007+ XML. You are calling the part
>   of POI that deals with OLE2 Office Documents. You need to call a
>   different part of POI to process this data (eg XSSF instead of HSSF)
>     at
>   org.apache.poi.poifs.storage.HeaderBlock.(HeaderBlock.java:131)
>     at
>   org.apache.poi.poifs.storage.HeaderBlock.(HeaderBlock.java:104)
>     at
>   org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem.(POIFSFileSystem.java:138)
>     at
>   org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.(HSSFWorkbook.java:322)
>     at
>   org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.(HSSFWorkbook.java:303)
>     at ExcelRead.main(ExcelRead.java:18)

The Java code is as follows:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;


public class ExcelRead {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("C:/Users/vinayakp/Desktop/Book.xlsx"));
        HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(file);
        HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
        while(rowIterator.hasNext()) {
            Row row = rowIterator.next();
            Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
            while(cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
                switch(cell.getCellType()) {
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                        System.out.print(cell.getBooleanCellValue() + "\t\t");
                        break;
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                        System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue() + "\t\t");
                        break;
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                        System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue() + "\t\t");
                        break;
                }
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
        file.close();    
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException ae) {
        ae.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

After deleting previous imports class then try to add

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory;


 private static void read(String path){
  Workbook workbook = null;
  FileInputStream fis = null;           
    try {
        File source = new File(path);
        if(source.exists()){
         fis = new FileInputStream(source);
         workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(source);

        }else{
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File path is not exist.", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }       

        Sheet sheet = null;           
        int lastRowNum = 0;
        int numSheets = workbook.getNumberOfSheets();         
        for(int i = 0; i < numSheets; i++) {              
            sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(i);
            if(sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows() > 0) {                    
                lastRowNum = sheet.getLastRowNum();                  
                int lastCellNum = 0;               
                for(Row row : sheet) {                  
                    Employee emp = new Employee();         

                    int numOfCell = row.getPhysicalNumberOfCells(); 
                    System.out.println("numOfCell:: "+numOfCell);
                    String stringValues [] = new String[numOfCell];
                    for(Cell cell : row) {
                       // cell = row.getCell(cellIndex);                        
                        int cellIndex = cell.getColumnIndex();                      
                        logger.info("cellIndex:: "+ cellIndex);
                         switch (cell.getCellType()) {

                         case Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA:
                            // printValue = "FORMULA value=" + cell.getCellFormula();
                             stringValues[cellIndex] = cell.getCellFormula();
                             break;

                         case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                             //printValue = "NUMERIC value=" + cell.getNumericCellValue();
                             System.out.println("Value is numeric:: "+ cell.getNumericCellValue());
                             stringValues[cellIndex]  = String.valueOf(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                             break;

                         case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                            // printValue = "STRING value=" + cell.getStringCellValue();
                             stringValues[cellIndex]  = cell.getStringCellValue();
                             break;

                         case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK:
                            // printValue = "STRING value=" + cell.getStringCellValue();
                             stringValues[cellIndex]  = cell.getStringCellValue();
                             break;   

                         default:
                         } 


                     }           

                    } 


                } 
            }            
        }     

        } catch (InvalidFormatException e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {          
            e.printStackTrace();
            logger.error(e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
        catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
        finally {
            if (fis != null) {
                try {
                    fis.close();
                    fis = null;
                    } catch (IOException ioEx) {
                        logger.error(ioEx.getMessage());
                } 
            }
        }    
     }
```

Comment: getting this : _Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xmlbeans/XmlObject
 at ExcelRead.main(ExcelRead.java:17)_

Comment: which libraries have you  added?

Comment: add xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar in your class path

Answer (score 3):

If you want to read a `.xls` file you must use `HSSF` (it supports only `.xls` format) but for `.xlsx` files you must use `XSSF` or another higher version API.

Comment: yeah know that fact. anyway thanks :) i got the ans, code is working fine. xml lib was missing

Comment: Which xml lib is this Vinayak?

Answer (score 1):

you are using the wrong class for reading the file `HSSFWorkbook` is for old excel format. use  `XSSFWorkbook` instead

**Edited:**
copied from http://www.coderanch.com/t/463779/java/java/read-xlsx-sheet-Client-Side.
did u do the same thing?

```
try { 
System.out.println("destDir==> "+destDir); 
XSSFWorkbook workBook = new XSSFWorkbook(destDir); 
XSSFSheet sheet = workBook.getSheetAt(0); 
totalRows = sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows(); 
System.out.println("total no of rows >>>>"+totalRows); 

} catch (IOException e) { 
e.printStackTrace(); 
}
```

**Edit 2:**
Learn about apache POI from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10005678/648157)

Comment: remove import HSSFWorkbook then import XSSFWorkbook

Comment: @MohammodHossain after doing it i get the follwing error _Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xmlbeans/XmlObject
 at ExcelRead.main(ExcelRead.java:20)_

Comment: @Vinayak check both links provided in edit to learn apache poi

Comment: Yeah you can say, my aim is to do the same

Comment: missed ooxml jar...code is working now..thank you @NaveenBabu