# Error messages while opening Excel sheet created by Java POI

Tags: excel, apache-poi

After generating the excel sheet using Java POI and opening the newly created Excel file I get a message box saying

```
Excel found unreadable content in "abc.xlxs" .Do you want to recover the contents of this workbook?If you trust the source of this workbook, click 'yes'.
```

And when I click 'yes' I get some message like this

```
Excel was able to open the file by repairing or removing the unreadable content
```

After that I can view the contents in the sheet. How can I remove all these kind of messages while opening it?

Comment: Did you make sure you generated the file with the most recent version of Apache POI?

Comment: you mean the library files?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13859307/1211000

Comment: Yes, make sure you're using POI 3.9 and not an older version

Comment: yes,currently I am using POI 3.9

Answer (score 0):

You should check if you use the right api:

- For .xls files you must use HSSF.
- For .xlsx files you must use XSSF or higher version api.

Check if you write your excel file correct.
And for the right answer, provide some code, please.