# Read Date values from Excel Sheet (Java)

Tags: java, apache-poi

I've a Java code which displays the contents of excel sheet. Now, when i'm working with *numeric/string/boolean* data it always gives me right result. Unlike, for testing my code i made few changes in the Excel and added a *date value* for example *4-sep-09*. On running my code, it returned undesired results. Code and the o/p is shown as follows. **How i can read and display date values from excel sheet?** I'm using Apache Poi. I could have done something like  `XSSFDateUtil` and check if the cell value is date or not using `if-else`? is that a possible solution?

Java Code:

```
FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File(FileName));
       System.out.println("The contents of sheet are:\n");
       XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
       XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
       Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
       while(rowIterator.hasNext()) {
           Row row = rowIterator.next(); 
           Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
           while(cellIterator.hasNext()) {
               Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
               switch(cell.getCellType()) {
                   case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                       System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue() + "\t\t");
                       break;
                   case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                       System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue() + "\t\t");
                       break;
               }
           }
           System.out.println("");
       }    
       file.close();
```

O/P i'm getting

```
ColA   | ColB....(few other columns)
32755.0|(other values)
```

Instead what i want that date value must be printed instead of number. My sheet is having *4-SEP-89* date under *ColA* and it is displaying some numbers.

Desired O/P

```
ColA    | ColB....(few other columns)
4-SEP-89|(other values)
```

**Note**:- **this is part of my code, which is running fine. Its giving no errors, however i need small change in the o/p as asked above.** i've been working on this for a while. i've asked questions related to displaying excel sheets before here- [Issue while reading Excel document (Java code)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13856466/issu-while-reading-excel-document-java-code) which is resolved along with couple of others. Thanks anyway.

Also, as far as i think, everything from excel, is read as a String (except boolean values)? Isn't that right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to look at [`DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted()`](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DateUtil.html)

DateUtil is a utility class that helps you deal with excel dates. It also has methods to get the Java Date from the `double` you get from the `Cell`

Comment: my file is in Excel 2007 so i'm using XSSF instead of HSSF and cannot find XSSFDateUtil

Comment: They're static methods on UtilDate so they're also accessible on HSSFUtilDate (a subclass of UtilDate). So it probably wouldn't have mattered much.