# Starting with Apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am new at apache POI. I have downloaded JARs but have no idea where to start. Can anyone suggest good links for getting started with. I checked on project site but not finding it helpful.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2253779/learning-apache-poi-for-java

Comment: start [here](http://poi.apache.org/)

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Please ask a more specific question.

Answer (score 2):

A while back, I created a few tutorials for doing some **very** basic POI operations that may be helpful to get started:

[Create an Excel File using Java and POI](http://obscuredclarity.blogspot.de/2011/12/create-excel-file-using-java-and-poi.html)

[Read Contents of an Excel File using Java and POI](http://obscuredclarity.blogspot.de/2011/12/read-contents-of-excel-file-using-java.html)

[Set Background Color and Add Border to a Cell in an Excel File Using Java and POI](http://obscuredclarity.blogspot.de/2011/12/set-background-color-and-add-border-to.html)

[Set Font Style in an Excel File Using Java and POI](http://obscuredclarity.blogspot.de/2011/12/set-font-style-in-excel-file-using-java.html)

[Get Sheet Names from an Excel File Using Java and POI](http://obscuredclarity.blogspot.de/2011/12/get-sheet-names-from-excel-file-using.html)

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you aim to do with POI. Do you want to generate files only for Excel? Other formats too?

There is plenty of docs and tutorials on the official website and on the web

- [Excel Quick Guide](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html)
- [Excel Samples](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/examples.html)
- [On Java-Connect](http://www.java-connect.com/category/apache-poi-tutorials/)
- [On Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=apache%20poi%20tutorials)